# How to get results from Prompt in Bot Framework Dialog

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am trying to get the response to builder.Prompt.choice(...); The list of choices gets loaded and when I make a choice nothing happens.

But it doesn't seems like   `function(session, results)` ever gets executed. 
`session.send("Choice Made)` and the other code doesn't get executed. How can I get my response. I'm not sure what is going wrong here. It looks just like code from the docs.

```
bot.dialog('LifecycleDialog', function (session, args) {

        var softwareEntity = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.intent.entities, 'Software');
        var choices = Object.keys(SoftwareDict[softwareEntity.entity]);

        builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Select a version by typing the number: ", choices, "Sorry I don't see that version.");
        },
        function (session, results) {
            session.send("Choice Made"); //DOES NOT WORK
                session.endDialogWithResult(results); //DOES NOT WORK

}).triggerAction({
    matches: 'LifecycleStatus'
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with a triggerAction? All the examples are just dialog with a slightly different syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The only difference is the dialog should have brackets [] instead of curly braces {}.

```
bot.dialog('LifecycleDialog', function (session, args) [

        var softwareEntity = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.intent.entities, 'Software');
        var choices = Object.keys(SoftwareDict[softwareEntity.entity]);

        builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Select a version by typing the number: ", choices, "Sorry I don't see that version.");
        },
        function (session, results) {
            session.send("Choice Made"); //DOES NOT WORK
                session.endDialogWithResult(results); //DOES NOT WORK

]).triggerAction({
    matches: 'LifecycleStatus'
});
```

Comment: You can find the selected choice in `results.response` object in the dialog handler after the prompt.

Comment: curly braces `{ }` were fine the functions in dialog should be enclosed in square `[ ]` braces.

Answer (score 3):

You should put the square brackets at the beginning of the functions part i.e. after the comma
Like " 'LifecycleDialog', **[** function (session, args) "

```
bot.dialog('LifecycleDialog', [
    function (session, args) {

    var softwareEntity = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.intent.entities, 'Software');
    var choices = Object.keys(SoftwareDict[softwareEntity.entity]);

    builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Select a version by typing the number: ", choices, "Sorry I don't see that version.");
    },
    function (session, results) {
        session.send("Choice Made"); //DOES NOT WORK
            session.endDialogWithResult(results); //DOES NOT WORK
    }

]).triggerAction({
matches: 'LifecycleStatus'
});
```